# Unable to launch app in Android device

Tags: android

I am unable to run my app on my android device. While launching the app it gives some IOException and cancel the app launching.

Like this :(in console)

[2010-09-18 02:45:53 - Lime] Android Launch!
[2010-09-18 02:45:53 - Lime] adb is running normally.
[2010-09-18 02:45:53 - Lime] Performing com.gtx.gpstrackinglime.splash activity launch
[2010-09-18 02:45:57 - Lime] Uploading Lime.apk onto device 'HT923GZ00530'
[2010-09-18 02:46:12 - Lime] Failed to upload Lime.apk on device 'HT923GZ00530'
[2010-09-18 02:46:12 - Lime] java.io.IOException: Unable to upload file: timeout
[2010-09-18 02:46:12 - Lime] Launch canceled!

Comment: You should really consider accept some answers.

Answer (score 0):

You werent able to upload the apk, do you have drivers installed for that handset? and running `adb devices` shows a device attached?

Comment: Any one help me.  same errors. cant run the apps on my device

Comment: One thing to try, is to compile an example app that comes with android sdk and try loading it. If it loads and runs the error is caused by your code, else it is caused by some kind of connectivity issue. You can also try loading your app from another PC, or loading it in a SD, loading the SD card on the handset and then try launching it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you jst need upgrade your usb driver, follow this ref link http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html, after upgrading you need to uncheck USB debugging, disconnect cable from device and then check USB debugging and connect cable to device again. this'll solve your problem..

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the platform-tools folder, that is in `android-sdk-folder/platform-tools`.

And inside this folder type this, with your phone disconnected from USB:

**on Linux:**  `./adb kill-server`  **"hit enter"** and type `./adb start-server`

**on Windows:**  `adb kill-server`  **"hit enter"** and type `adb start-server`

Now connect your phone and type:

**on Linux:**  `./adb devices`

**on Windows:**  `adb devices`

Now you must see your device ID on the Screen. That worked for me.

Comment: The address is not available anymore. If you can't find an updated URL, I think it will be the best if you delete your answer.